# Is there a noun that goes with the verb "inaugurate"?

Tags: word-request

As the heading suggests, I'm wondering whether there is a general noun that goes with the verb "inaugurate", to refer to the person who has been inaugurated, or whether we always have to use a more specific noun (phrase), such as "the new president"; "the new minister" etc?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the kind of sentence you are thinking of?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You can inaugurate anything that can be inaugurated: a president (in US politics. Prime Ministers aren't 'inaugurated'), policy, system, period, company, scheme, campaign, (and so on _ad infinitum_). Are you only concentrating on (1) to put someone into an official position with a ceremony and ignoring (2 to put something into use or action officially and (3) to mark the beginning of a new period, style, or activity?

Comment: I think that OP wants a word that means "a person who has just been inaugurated", but I'm not entirely sure. OP: Please note the description of the "word-request" tag.

Comment: The noun from _inaugurate_ is _inauguration_, but that is a ceremony, not the person starting a new role.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Quite right; that's exactly what I was after. I realise it was a bad OP – I posted it in haste (due to lack of time) which I shouldn't have, and which was quite disrespectful (wasting other people's time). I can only apologise...

Comment: @Helen No problem, but could you edit the question to make it clearer? Otherwise it might get closed (it already has 3 out of 5 close votes), which would be a shame since I think it's basically a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A person who has very recently been ceremonially inaugurated in a role, position, title, etc, is very occasionally called an **inauguree**. I note that the spell checker in Google Chrome does not like that word. I cannot find it in any online dictionary, or the Oxford English Dictionary, however it can be found in academic discussions and press stories related to ceremonies such as swearing-in of (US) presidents, English mayors, etc. Consider using a phrase such as 'the inaugurated person', or of writing the text in such a way that the problem is avoided, by using e.g. 'the new president', 'Mayor Jones', etc. Try to avoid the sin of too much [elegant variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:The_problem_with_elegant_variation#:%7E:text=Elegant%20variation%20distracts%20the%20reader,is%20the%20Bishop%20of%20Rome.) (the attempt to relieve repetition by replacing words with synonyms).

A new British Prime Minister is not 'inaugurated' in a public ceremony; he or she visits the current monarch and kisses his or her hand in a private ritual.

> George Bush was so eager to take over the new job that he was even
> signing notes to aides with ''The **Inauguree**.''  (New York Times)

> Constitutional experts abounded at George Washington's inauguration.
> The **inauguree** himself was a signer of the Constitution (Blog at
> Wallbuilders.com)

> The room itself is decorated with the royal arms in the centre, the
> Cross of St. George to the left, and the arms of the town of Bristol
> to the right. Standing at the “high deise” of the Guildhall, before
> his fellow common councillors and members of the “Comyns,” the
> **inauguree** swore allegiance to the monarch (Account of 15th century
> swearing-in of mayors of Bristol)

Comment: Thank you so much – this is exactly what I was after! In hindsight I realise it was a stupid question, which I furthermore posted in haste (which I shouldn't have), yet you took the time to decipher it and give me this excellent answer! I can only thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: @Helen - interesting questions are always worth posting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a term that covers important government roles like president, prime minister, judge, etc., I would use *official*.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your answer; I've upvoted it though, because your guess as to what I was after was as good as any, seeing my OP wasn't very clear... :)

Answer (score -1):

You are probably trying to find out what words are often used together with "inaugurate"- Basically, you are asking what **collocations** "inaugurate" has.

Whether you are a learner or a teacher you can start using **Oxford Collocation Dictionary**. It allows you to resolve issues like this without any external help. And the advice you receive here on collocations will never come even close to what a dictionary can suggest. The one specific dictionary I mentioned comes in the form of software and has a search function. It's extremely convenient and helpful. I used it in college everytime I had to write a paper or an essay in English and always received top grades.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.  I'm not sure that collations are what the OP wants, but even if so, this post doesn't actually suggest any collations for inaugurate. So it isn't a good answer.